# How to tell Ruby not to serialize an attribute or how to overload marshal_dump properly?

Tags: ruby, marshalling

I have an attribute in my AR:B that is not serializeable.

```
o = Discussion.find(6)
Marshal.dump(o)

TypeError: no marshal_dump is defined for class Proc
       from (irb):10:in `dump'
```

I know the culprit and what I want is to set this variable to nil
before any serialization takes place.

I can do this but I'm stuck with the proper way to override marshal_dump

```
 def marshal_dump
   @problem = nil
   # what is the right return here?
 end
```

Or is there is way to tell Ruby or AR not to serialize an object?

Answer (score 3):

Your specialized `marshal_dump` should return an object containing the data you want to serialize. That object will be passed back to `marshal_load` at load time.

In this case, I'm assuming the data you want to dump corresponds to all AR attributes (and only those), so I'd try:

```
def marshal_dump
  attributes
end

def marshal_load(data)
  send :attributes=, data, false  # false to override even protected attributes
end
```

Comment: Thanks Marc.

The right code would be instance_variable_set(:@attributes, data). Otherwise, it will raise an exception.

Comment: @GregMoreno: No, I mean to call `ActiveRecord::Base#attributes=` which is a useful method to set attributes of an AR. If you want to set an attribute in `marshal_load`, you can simply write `@some_attr = data[:some_attr]`, for example.

Comment: A late comment, but to get this to work for a ARB I had to do `initialize` before setting any attribute with the auto ARB methods in `marshal_load`, or e.g. `initialize(data)` in my case were I just marshal some attributes. This is in `Rails 4`.

Comment: ...perhaps there is a better or more correct way to do it.