# How to make an attribute transient (not marshalled)

Tags: ruby, marshalling

I'm using Ruby 1.8.6 and have a class (*not* an ActiveRecord class) that I want to cache using memcache-client, which serializes it with `Marshal.dump` before storing it in the cache. However, it has an instance variable (which *does* refer to an ActiveRecord class) that I don't want to serialize, as I don't want multiple objects running around corresponding to the same database row. Instead, I want to set the attribute to refer to the appropriate object (which I already have a reference to) after the serialized object is loaded from the cache and reconstructed.

What's the easiest way to prevent only one attribute from being marshalled?

(I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767793/how-to-tell-ruby-not-to-serialize-an-attribute-or-how-to-overload-marshal-dump-p), but the given answer appears to apply only to ActiveRecord classes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html

> When dumping an object the method marshal_dump will be called.
>   marshal_dump must return a result containing the information necessary
>   for marshal_load to reconstitute the object. The result can be any
>   object.
>
> When loading an object dumped using marshal_dump the object is first
>   allocated then marshal_load is called with the result from
>   marshal_dump. marshal_load must recreate the object from the
>   information in the result.

so the question you are linking to also applies to you. just override those two methods and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, but how do I get a hash containing the values of all the attributes (so that I can remove the one I don't want)? The `attributes` method mentioned in the answer I linked to is available only for ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: you have access to ALL the attributes of your class. what do you need an attributes hash for?

Comment: So I just have to list them all?

Comment: you could also use some meta-programming http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variables

Comment: [Found a relevant question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830368/in-ruby-how-can-i-get-instance-variables-in-a-hash-instead-of-an-array) Thanks!